# stop Save password window in chrome

Tags: karate

I am new to karate UI and web automation, while I am trying to enter credentials chrome is throwing a pop up for saving the password, its happening every time I try to login.

I used  * mouse().move(100, 200).go()& * dialog(true) to avoid pop up but it dint help either.

Kindly help!

Comment: if the linked answer does not help, please contribute code

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks!! I would love to contribute to the code, could you please let me know if there is any onboarding procedure (any document etc.)

Comment: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide